# Python: BeautifulSoup not always getting all text data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i've got a strange problem with my webscraper. I am trying to get the data from a website using BeautifulSoup.

My code works on 90% of all links i've tried out but on a few it does not read the page fully.

The text that intrests me is "1152x864"
When checking the soure code on my browser i clearly see the text:

```
<li class="x-block-grid-item">
    <h3 style="margin: 0 0 0.35em;font-size: 1em;letter-spacing: 0.05em;line-height: 1">Resolution</h3>

    <p class="man">1152x864</p>
</li>
```

But when I try to get the source via BeautifulSoup it only shows this:

```
<li class="x-block-grid-item">
    <h3 style="margin: 0 0 0.35em;font-size: 1em;letter-spacing: 0.05em;line-height: 1">Resolution</h3>
</li>
```

This is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://prosettings.net/counterstrike/fer/'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("li",{"class":"x-block-grid-item"})
cont_res = containers[8].p.text 
print("Res: " + cont_res)
```

When I try a different link for example:
    my_url = 'https://prosettings.net/counterstrike/fallen/'
Everything works fine.

Comment: I find using `containers[8].p` kind of weird, that really works ? I'd use find : `containers[8].find('p')`

Comment: Using requests instead of urllib I get all of the content, that is when I print out what has been scraped, the <p class='man'> tags are there with dimensions, but .text won't print out what's in those containers, just what's inside the <li> tags.

Comment: It works if you use `lxml` instead of `html.parser`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It should not disappoint you:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://prosettings.net/counterstrike/fer/'

res = urlopen(URL).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, "lxml")
cont_res = ' '.join([item.find(class_="man").text for item in soup.find_all(class_="x-block-grid-item") if "Resolution" in item.text])
# or using .select()
# cont_res = ' '.join([item.select_one(".man").text for item in soup.select(".x-block-grid-item") if "Resolution" in item.text])
print("Res: " + cont_res)
```

Output:

```
Res: 1152x864
```

Comment: Works.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm used to BeautifulSoup.text printing out the text of every tag and its children, but there may be something funny going on with these `<p>`'s in particular. At any rate, you're not getting the right soup, so maybe try `requests` instead of `urllib`, and then dig straight for the `<p>` tags with `bs4`.

```
site = 'https://prosettings.net/counterstrike/fer/'
r = requests.get(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
list2 = soup.find_all('p', class_='man')
for item in list2:
    if item.find('p'):
        print(item.text)
```

Gives me all the class="man" `<p>` tags' info:

```
400
2.50
1000
125
1.00
0
6
1
1152x864
4:3
stretched
240
```

It's literally just the Resolution tag. No idea why.